# Count instances from a selected set of 2 unified columns

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table called "matches" where I save 2 teams from a soccer match.

```
-------------------------
| home_club | away_club |
-------------------------
|           |           |
-------------------------
```

And I have a query that returns all the clubs from that table, both the home and away clubs through UNION:

```
SELECT home_club AS clubs FROM matches UNION SELECT away_club FROM matches
```

Now I have a results set called "clubs" and I wish to count how many times each has appeared in the "matches" table. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how many times each has appeared in the `matches` table, then you need to get rid of the `union` in the subquery.  The `union` is going to remove duplicates.

Here is how you would get a count:

```
select club, count(*) as NumAppears
from (SELECT home_club AS club FROM matches
      UNION ALL
      SELECT away_club FROM matches 
     ) m
group by club;
```

Note the `UNION` is replaced with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
select sum(count) as Matches, Club from
(select count(*) as count, home_club as Club from matches group by home_club
union all
select count(*) as count, away_club as Club from matches group by away_club ) a
group by a.clubs
```

Comment: Yeah, i meant that, and somehow forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    M.clubs,
    COUNT(M.clubs) [count]
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            home_club AS clubs
        FROM
            matches 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            away_club
        FROM
            matches
    ) M
GROUP BY
    M.clubs
```

Comment: I think this one only counts the number of instances they have in the "clubs" results set but not in the matches table. All it returns is 1s for each row.

Comment: See if changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` (to prevent the removal of duplicate club names) does the trick.